# Enable button if all rows below have been deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created with JQuery a table where I can add a certain text by pressing a button.

As you can see Product 2 and Product 3 can only be added once. Product 4 can be added several times. All text that is inserted can also be deleted by pressing the `x`-button.

```js
$(".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm").on("click", this.ourClickDispatcher.bind(this))
$("#tableProd").on("click", ".btn.btn-danger.btn-sm.deleteMe", this.deleteRow.bind(this))

function deleteRow(e) {
  let deleteBtn = $(e.target).closest(".deleteMe");
  deleteBtn.closest('tr').remove()
}

function ourClickDispatcher(e) {
  let targetButton = $(e.target).closest(".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm")
  let targetButtonParent = targetButton[0].parentElement.parentElement

  targetButtonParent.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `
             <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <img src="" alt="" height="42" width="42">
                    <a href="">
                        Test Product2
                    </a>
                </td>    
                <td class="deleteMe">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteMe">x</button>
                    </td>   
             </tr>
            `)
  if (targetButton.hasClass('product3') || targetButton.hasClass('product2')) {
    targetButton.attr("disabled", true);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableProd" style="float: left;" class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Product 2</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="product2" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product2">
                                            Add Product 2
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product 3</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="product3" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product3">
                                            Add Product 3
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product 4</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="product4" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product4">
                                            Add Product 4
                                     
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My problem is that if I delete all rows below a `disabled` button I cannot add any new rows again. This case is shown in the picture below:

[image]

Any suggestions how to `enable` the button if all rows below have been deleted?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `$(".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm").attr("disabled", false);` at the end of `deleteRow` method.

```js
$(".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm").on("click", this.ourClickDispatcher.bind(this))
$("#tableProd").on("click", ".btn.btn-danger.btn-sm.deleteMe", this.deleteRow.bind(this))

function deleteRow(e) {
  let deleteBtn = $(e.target).closest(".deleteMe");
  deleteBtn.closest('tr').remove();
  $(".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm").attr("disabled", false);
}

function ourClickDispatcher(e) {
  let targetButton = $(e.target).closest(".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm")
  let targetButtonParent = targetButton[0].parentElement.parentElement

  targetButtonParent.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `
             <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <img src="" alt="" height="42" width="42">
                    <a href="">
                        Test Product2
                    </a>
                </td>    
                <td class="deleteMe">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteMe">x</button>
                    </td>   
             </tr>
            `)
  if (targetButton.hasClass('product3') || targetButton.hasClass('product2')) {
    targetButton.attr("disabled", true);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableProd" style="float: left;" class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Product 2</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="product2" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product2">
                                            Add Product 2
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product 3</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="product3" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product3">
                                            Add Product 3
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product 4</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="product4" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product4">
                                            Add Product 4
                                     
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added you one new function to your javascript

```
    function enableButton(elemId) {
        console.log(document.getElementById(elemId));
        if (!document.getElementById(elemId)) {
            var str = elemId.split('_');
            var button = $('#'+str[1]);
            $('#'+str[1]).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }
```

and i also set ids on your html buttons

```js
$(".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm").on("click", this.ourClickDispatcher.bind(this))
 $("#tableProd").on("click", ".btn.btn-danger.btn-sm.deleteMe", this.deleteRow.bind(this))

 function deleteRow(e) {
    let deleteBtn = $(e.target).closest(".deleteMe");
    let itemId = e.target.getAttribute('id');
    deleteBtn.closest('tr').remove();
    enableButton(itemId);
 }

 function enableButton(elemId) {
  if (!document.getElementById(elemId)) {
   var str = elemId.split('_');
   var button = $('#'+str[1]);
   $('#'+str[1]).removeAttr('disabled');
  }
 }

 function ourClickDispatcher(e) {
    let targetButton = $(e.target).closest(".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm");
    let targetButtonParent = targetButton[0].parentElement.parentElement;

    var elemId = 'item_'+e.target.getAttribute('id');
    targetButtonParent.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `
              <tr>
                 <td></td>
                 <td>
                     <img src="" alt="" height="42" width="42">
                     <a href="">
                         Test Product2
                     </a>
                 </td>    
                 <td class="deleteMe">
                         <button  id='`+elemId+`' type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteMe">x</button>
                     </td>   
              </tr>
             `)
    if (targetButton.hasClass('product3') || targetButton.hasClass('product2')) {
      targetButton.attr("disabled", true);
   }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableProd" style="float: left;" class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Product 2</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" id='btn2' data-exists="product2" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product2">
            Add Product 2
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product 3</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" id='btn3' data-exists="product3" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product3">
            Add Product 3
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product 4</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" id='btn4' data-exists="product4" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product4">
         Add Product 4
         </button>                            
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```